# UITableView lags when scrolling with multiple cell types

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapbox, uber-api

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this topic but bear with me cause I didn't find any solution to my specific problem.

First of all, my entire app is in code (no storyboard). I am creating a tableView (where I get data from a backend) with multiple cell types. The cells are in constant order meaning that the first cell will always be the same type as any other first cell (not sure if you get my point but technically the cell types are constant to a specific indexPath.

So the problem is I have methods that dequeues the specific cell for each indexPath. In one of my cells, I have a MapboxStatic map, which returns an image of a map from Mapbox's servers. Let's say the cell is off the screen at initial run time, if I scroll fast enough, the tableView will hold off for a second or so to load the image returned (I tried loading it asynchronously on the main queue still with no changes).

Now my other problem is with the UberRides button, it also lags when scrolling (same issue).

It's worth mentioning that if I scroll through the tableView once (with the lag), and I scroll up and back down it does not lag anymore but I guess it's because the dequeued cell is still in memory.

If you need any other details please leave a comment.

[EDIT] Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return reserveTableViewCell(at: indexPath)
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        return dateTimeTableViewCell(at: indexPath)
    } else if indexPath.section == 3 {
        return descriptionTableViewCell(at: indexPath)
    } else if indexPath.section == 4 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return mapTableViewCell(at: indexPath)
        } else {
            return uberTableViewCell(at: indexPath)
        }
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: defaultCell, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

private func reserveTableViewCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reserveCell, for: indexPath) as! ReserveTableViewCell
    return cell
}

private func descriptionTableViewCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: descriptionCell, for: indexPath) as! DescriptionTableViewCell
    return cell
}

private func dateTimeTableViewCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: dateTimeCell, for: indexPath) as! DateTimeTableViewCell
    return cell
}

private func mapTableViewCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: mapCell) as! MapTableViewCell
    cell.detailController = self
    return cell
}

private func uberTableViewCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: uberCell, for: indexPath) as! UberTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Best

Comment: I think you should post some of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

Comment: Sure, I just added it

Comment: Is your images cached ?

Comment: They get cached after first load but they are images of location maps so impossible to cache them all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, creating your cells is slow. It's hard to give you any suggestions now knowing what takes so much time. Use [time profiler](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/418/) to determine the problematic code.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need overlays, you could try to use [`MGLMapSnapshotter`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLMapSnapshotter.html). [Here](https://github.com/mapbox/store-locator-ios/blob/master/mapbox-store-locator/ThemePickerViewController.swift) is an example of how a MGLMapSnapshot can be used with a table view.

Comment: I'm already using Mapbox Static, which returns a snapshot as well. But I noticed that the scroll is laggy because the cell cannot be displayed without the image loaded